# Laptop (thinkpad x201t) with i7 overheats and shuts down. How to manage turbo boost?

Tags: laptop, overheating, turbo-boost

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad [x201 tablet](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X201_Tablet) with Ubuntu 11.04. When I run mathematica or stress, the laptop overheats and shuts down. I loose all my work.

I would think that turbo boost (for intel i7) turns on and doesn't turn off when the temperature is too hot. Anyway to manage that?

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: i edited the post. 11.04

Answer (score 4):

There is a [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/751689) on launchpad which fits your tablet/laptop observation problem.

Reading through this, there are several suggestions, for example

- In your BIOS - make sure you are using the latest BIOS version (see the Vendor website for any updates
- Also in your BIOS - look for "Advanced Thermal Management" - Set this to "Balanced" rather than "Maximum"
- Look at installing the package "thinkfan" from the repositories - **NOTE THE WARNING IN THE BUG REPORT** - read the documentation first, as incorrect usage can cause serious damage
- Take a close look at your fans - clean out any dust etc

Comment: may I know why the Thermal Management setting should be set to Balanced instead of Maximum? My ThinkPad is overheating too, and incidentally my setting is set to Maximum. Thank you.

Comment: balanced is the automatic setting used on battery - maximum is for AC.  Thus forcing "balanced" makes the laptop use battery defaults which basically slows various settings to reduce power - and therefore prevents overheating